# Axios GET request timeouts randomly

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, timeout, axios-retry

We are working on a React app, which makes REST API calls using Axios. And we are randomly seeing request timeouts. We checked the network connection and it was fine (100 MBPS connection). We checked our server logs, the request reached the server and it got processed without any errors. But the client never got back the response. I am adding the code we use to make those api calls below. If you find any issue with the code, a solution will be much appreciated. If you think that the code is looking good, then please give us some tips on resolving/debugging the timeout. I am also adding the error below.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import axiosRetry from 'axios-retry';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

axios.defaults.timeout = 30000;
axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  const updatedConfig = { ...config };
  updatedConfig.headers['X-CORRELATION-ID'] = v4();
  return updatedConfig;
});
axiosRetry(axios, {
  retries: 3,
  retryDelay: (retryCount) => retryCount * 1000,
});

axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: `${requestURL}`,
    headers: {
      authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

```
{
    "error": {
        "message": "timeout of 30000ms exceeded",
        "name": "Error",
        "stack": "Error: timeout of 30000ms exceeded\n at e.exports (https://file.js:2:2141051)\n at XMLHttpRequest.h.ontimeout (https://file.js:2:2140157)",
        "config": {
            "url": "requestURL",
            "method": "get",
            "headers": {
                "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                "authorization": "Bearer TOKEN",
                "X-CORRELATION-ID": "UDID"
            },
            "transformRequest": [null],
            "transformResponse": [null],
            "timeout": 30000,
            "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
            "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
            "maxContentLength": -1,
            "axios-retry": {
                "retryCount": 0,
                "lastRequestTime": 1597096169071
            }
        },
        "code": "ECONNABORTED"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: _But the client never got back the response_ -- if you didn't get a response from the server, that's not a React problem. Have you confirmed the response was returned in the dev tools? If a request is timing out, again, not a React problem. What are you seeing in the dev tools in your browser?

Comment: @Yatrix thanks for your reply. I agree and this couldn't be a react problem. But random timeout without a proper reason is a huge issue for us, we added about react so that the StackOverflow will know more about the issue.

Comment: If you've ruled out React, best not to include the tag. It sounds like a problem on your server. If nothing is being logged, that sounds like a problem with your logging. A timeout after 30s is pretty bad. You're likely experiencing a long-running query or your server is low on CPU/memory, so it's getting pegged randomly by other processes and then unable to finish the request in 30s.

Comment: @Yatrix Server is fine, we checked the logs on server, the request got processed in 0.022 seconds. And we have added more resource to the server to rule out low on CPU/memory scenario. Everything is being logged, the request and also the response-error. What else do you want us to log?

Comment: Okay, so in the browser, you see a 200 with the data you’re expecting in the Network tab then, right?

Comment: @Yatrix In browser the request failed due to timeout. With status code 0 and no data. That's the issue here.

Comment: Okay, if the response isn't a 200, that doesn't sound like a client issue. Try recreating the client out of the equation and seeing if it happens with Postman or curl.